# Issue with @PutMapping URL in SpringBoot 2

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger-2.0

I am having a weird issue with @PutMapping in SpringBoot 2 Rest API and not sure what wrong with my swagger 2 configurations.

For some reason, For URL "orders/v3/{id}", Swagger 2 documentation doesn't get displayed but If I change it to "order/{id}", It displays properly. It seems Swagger 2 doesn't like it when URL depth is more than 2. Is there some configuration that I am missing?

```
@PutMapping(value = "/orders/v3/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public @ResponseBody OrderResponse updateOrder(@PathVariable final Long orderId,
        @RequestBody @Valid final OrderData orderData) throws ServiceException {
        return orderService.updateOrder(orderId, orderData);
    }
```

I am very new to this so not sure how to fix this. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your swagger config - the class with `@EnableSwagger2` annotation?

Comment: Are you using tomcat?